# are all partial orders subsets of some lattice?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Take a partially ordered set, $(X,\succ)$. Does there exist a Lattice $(Y,\succ')$, such that $X\subset Y$ and $\forall x,x'\in X$, $$x\succ x'\iff x\succ'x'$$

A more formal statement of this question: For any partially ordered set, $(X,\succ)$, does there exist a Lattice $(Y,\succ')$ and a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ that is order embedding?

I apologize if this question may have an obvious reference, but such a reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes; you want the [Dedekind-MacNeille completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion) of the partial order.

Comment: But I don't want a complete order on Y. The DMN completion gives us a complete order right?

Comment: No, it’s the smallest complete lattice containing the partial order. Check the link.

Comment: @Daniel I think you're misremembering the notion of "complete" here - a lattice is complete if infima and suprema of arbitrary subsets exist. I believe you're conflating this with the notion of a *total* (or linear) order. The DM-completion is not a linear order unless the original partial order was.

Comment: perfect thanks to both of you, this was my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, analogously to Dedekind cuts there is a way to ["complete"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion) a partial order to form a lattice.